# mysql_query() não executa

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou a tentar testar se a minha base de dados se conectou corretamente apartir duma query, mas aparentemente o mysql_query() não executa e não altera a minha tabela. O meu código é este:

```
<?php
//conecta a base de dados
$dbc = mysql_connect('localhost', 'dbweb', 'notime');
if(!$dbc)
{
    die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
}

//seleciona a base de dados
$db_select = mysql_select_db('goaheadmakemyday', $dbc);
if($db_select)
{
    die("Can't connect : " . mysql_error());
}

//teste
$query = "UPDATE Colaborador SET Nome='Ola' WHERE ColNum='0'";
$resultado = mysql_query($query);

//Pequena parte da minha tabela:
//ColNum  Nome
//0       Simeão Lopes
//1       Olavo Bettencourt
//2       Sandro Vidal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu código o problema é quando a conexão é feita com sucesso `$db_select` recebe `true`, entra no if e fatalmente cai no `die()` e mata seu script. A solução para isso é negar a condição ou fazer uma verificação inline.

As funções mysql já foram removidas do php7, o mais indicado é utilizar o MySQLi ou PDO para fazer consultas em banco de dados.

```
$db_select = mysql_select_db('goaheadmakemyday', $dbc);
if(!$db_select)
{
    die("Can't connect : " . mysql_error());
}
```

Inline

```
mysql_select_db('goaheadmakemyday', $dbc) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!